# How to add a prefix to a input value and pass it to the backend as well in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, inputbox

This my Input field:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label class="form-label fw-bold text-muted" >Em Code</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">xyz.</div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="em_code" type="number" value="{{ old('em_code') }}">
        @error('em_code')
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

And as expected in my controller in returns only the number that's passed on.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->em_code);
}
```

Now I want it to return me the value as xyz.####

Of course I can concatenate it in my controller using the following -

```
'em_code' => 'bZm.'.$request->em_code,
```

But I want it concatenated from the blade input file,because I'm going to **validate** it as **Unique**. But in my **database** it is stored as **bZm.1111**. So in case of a input of *1111* the validation rule *will not pass any exception*. However, *mySql will return an error* because this column marked **unique** there.

So, in order to get an proper check for unique **em_code** I'm trying to get it concatenated from the input and pass it as that to the controller.

You're welcome to give some other solution for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Using javacript?

Comment: `$emCode = 'xyz.' . $request->em_code`?

Comment: Why don't you use it like this? 

```<input class="form-control" name="em_code" type="number" value="xyz.{{ old('em_code') }}">```

or you can get the result by adding a hidden input for prefix


```<input class="form-control" name="prefix" type="hidden" value="xyz.">```

```dd($request->prefix);```

Comment: @brombeer I  updated my question please check it.

Comment: @Gireada I  updated my question please check it

Comment: The simplest solution is to add a hidden input with your prefix and extract value from the request.   ```<input class="form-control" name="prefix" type="hidden" value="bZm.">```

  Are you using javascript to check the value?

Comment: If I were to use hidden value I could have concatenated it in the controller. I need it to be passed together. I'm using Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a form request class, you can prepare for validation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'em_code' => 'bZm.' . $this->em_code,
    ]);
}
```